# PHP Math with an array

Tags: php, arrays, math, while-loop

I'm trying to code a function that will add up the earnings of the day. Here's my query

```
SELECT company_profit
FROM run_sheet_log
WHERE company_id = 1
    AND created_date >= $today
    AND created_date < $next_day"
```

Now here is my issue, when I fetch the array how would I get the array to add up each variable together to echo the earnings?

Ex: http://gyazo.com/0872a625d52cb138458fd26a9ba46b72 now if you add it all up it should come out to $64,241

PHP

```
$today_earnings = array();
$earnings_query = $sql->query("SELECT company_profit FROM run_sheet_log WHERE company_id = 1 AND created_date >= $today AND created_date < $next_day");
    while($earnings_data = $sql->fetch_array($earnings_query)){
        $today_earnings[] = array("company_profit"=>$earnings_data["company_profit"]);


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add it in SQL with `SELECT SUM(company_profit) AS total_profit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` function:

```
SELECT SUM(company_profit) AS company_profit_sum
FROM run_sheet_log
WHERE company_id = 1
    AND created_date >= $today
    AND created_date < $next_day"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm going to use this on my site Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept this as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add the values to an accumulator variable.

```
$total_earnings = 0;
while($earnings_data = $sql->fetch_array($earnings_query)){
    $total_earnings += $earnings_data["company_profit"];
}
```

But it would be simpler to just have your query use `SELECT SUM(company_profit)`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still new to PHP and MYSQL

Comment: What programming languages aren't you new to? Adding a value to a variable in a loop is pretty much the same in all of them.

Comment: Rude @Barmar...not necessary or constructive. We were all new at one time, so calm it down.

Comment: @Jusmark123 It's a pet peeve -- "new to PHP" is not necessarily the same as "new to computer programming". But did you really need to bring up something I said over a year ago?